# Adding cookie to 'get' request to log in a website with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, google-apps-script

I've been trying to make a simple script work for the past couple of days and have not been successful so far.

Here is the problem:

The authentification on the website (like on many) consists of a first 'Post' request, which redirects you with a 302 response, and then a 'Get' request, to go on the home page logged in.

So, I'm trying to log in with a POST request, get the cookie included in the response, then add this cookie to my GET request.

Here is my code:

```
var headers = {
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Request' : '1',
  'User-Agent' :    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
  'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
  'Accept-Language' : 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,it;q=0.2,es;q=0.2'
};

var payload = {
  'ptl' : 'edt',
  'codensa' : 'pblv',
  'taiga_user' : 'user',
  'taiga_mdp' : 'mdp',
  'submit' : 'connexion'
};

var options = {
  'method'  : 'POST',
  'headers': headers,
  'payload' : payload,
  'followRedirects' : false
};

var login = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://etudiant.archi.fr/taiga/etd/pages/login.php', options);

var login_cookie = login.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'].split(';')[0];

return login_cookie;
```

And then, my GET request :

```
var headers2 = {
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Request' : '1',
  'User-Agent' :    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
  'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Accept-Language' : 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,it;q=0.2,es;q=0.2',
  'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
  'Cookie' : login_cookie,
};

var options2 = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'headers': headers2,
  'followRedirects' : false
};

var index = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://etudiant.archi.fr/taiga/etd/pages/index.php?im', options2);
```

And this doesn't work...

However, I suppose my script is kind of correct, since in my headers2, if I replace 'login_cookie' with an actual cookie that I get manually with my browser, it works!

Can anyone help me? I've tried everything...

Comment: So your issue is actually with grabbing the cookie from the response, right? It seems like you can send a cookie with your request correctly; you're having difficulty using the `Set-Cookie` in the response. Is that right?

Comment: I think my issue is that the cookie seems 'incorrect' or simply expired. The Set-Cookie seems to work fine aswell, my variable login_cookie equals "PHPSESSID=*somegenericcookiename*".